# How come 2 inserts with same PK succeed? How can I update a duplicate key?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an application which from what I understand uses `SQLiteDatabase`.
I see that 2 insert of the same data (same PK) do not seem to fail.

```
Uri res = context.getContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI, values);
res = context.getContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI, values);
```

So whe I print `res` I see:

```
content://application_id/my_table_name/10  
content://application_id/my_table_name/11
```

Does this mean that the row was inserted 2 times with ids 10 & 11?

But how is that possible if I am inserting 2 rows with the same id?
How can I verify what is happening?
My actual problem: I am interested in doing something like on duplicate PK update and noticed this

Comment: Im not sure, just an idea. Does this table has an auto increment column?

Comment: @whymatter:No it is: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table_name (contact_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, contact_name TEXT NOT NULL, contact_address TEXT  NULL);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that the row was inserted 2 times with ids 10 & 11?

Presumably. You would have to talk to whoever implemented the `ContentProvider` and ask them.

> But how is that possible if I am inserting 2 rows with the same id?

You would have to talk to whoever implemented the `ContentProvider` and ask them. Nobody else on the face of the planet can answer that question. For all you know, the `ContentProvider` is not backed by SQLite and has no concept of a primary key. Or, perhaps the primary key is an `_ID` column, not one of the columns from your `ContentValues`.

> How can I verify what is happening?

You would have to talk to whoever implemented the `ContentProvider` and ask them. Only they know where and how they are storing the data.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my confusion. I see where to look now. I see that we end up with insertWithOnConflict and CONFLICT_REPLACE. That is like on duplicate key update right?

Comment: @Jim: Yes. That will update an existing row if there is a primary key match, otherwise it will insert the new row. Whether `CONFLICT_REPLACE` is the right answer for your particular `ContentProvider`, I cannot say.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to be the field for the CONTENT_URI unique?
Have you checked that the field is UNIQUE?

I think that the id field will be set to auto-increment.

If you set the field for CONTENT_URI to UNIQUE you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`